# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named cffi

Tags: django, postgresql, mod-wsgi, wsgi, pypy

I developed a platform with django + wsgi + pypy + postgresql + postgis, everything works fine in development environment, but in production it sends error 500 and in the apache log it says ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named cffi

my config apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/plataform/project/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/user/plataform/project:/home/user/env/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup project

    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/user/plataform/project/media/
    Alias /static /home/user/plataform/project/static/

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/static>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

my pip freeze

```
cffi==1.6.0
Django==1.11.7
django-cors-headers==2.1.0
django-filter==1.1.0
djangorestframework==3.7.3
greenlet==0.4.9
Markdown==2.6.9
olefile==0.44
Pillow==4.3.0
psycopg2cffi==2.7.7
python-stdnum==1.7
pytz==2017.3
readline==6.2.4.1
six==1.11.0
uWSGI==2.0.15
```

Log Apache:

```
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:49.727998 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4975:tid 139854422423424] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:49.728151 2017] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4975:tid 139854422423424] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:49.729853 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4975:tid 139854422423424] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:49.729893 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4975:tid 139854422423424] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608678 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039] mod_wsgi (pid=4978): Target WSGI script '/home/user/plataform/project/project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608785 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039] mod_wsgi (pid=4978): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/plataform/project/project/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608821 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608859 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/plataform/project/project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608957 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.608974 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609017 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609032 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609090 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609112 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609256 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     app_config.import_models()
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609277 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609366 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609389 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609451 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     __import__(name)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609465 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609580 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609593 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609671 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.609686 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 124, in __new__
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610123 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610139 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610194 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610216 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610429 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610446 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610507 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610521 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610608 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610621 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610637 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610646 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610660 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     __import__(name)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610668 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 2, in <module>
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610706 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]     from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import (
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610733 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039]   File "/home/user/env/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610870 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039] raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
[Tue Dec 12 11:15:59.610901 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 4978:tid 139854259615488] [remote ::1:30039] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named cffi
```

Comment: Maybe a mixture of different configurations.  You say you use PyPy, but the log files seem to point to CPYthon 2.7.12.

Comment: You haven't created a Python virtual environment using pypy and then try and use it with mod_wsgi (which is compiled or Python 2.7) have you? You can't force mod_wsgi to work with a different Python version/distribution than it was compiled for. You can't use pypy with mod_wsgi at all. It can only be compiled for CPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean installation of pypy and created a new virtual environment, then changed the conf. of apache for this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/plataform/project/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/user/plataform/project:/home/user/env/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup project
    WSGIPassAuthorization On

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/project>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /home/user/plataform/project/media
    Alias /static/ /home/user/plataform/project/static

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/static>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/plataform/project/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

and everything worked well